# Legality of space colonization

Tags: united-states, space

Let's assume that I have all the resources to be able to travel to Mars or any other celestial body and colonize it. It is legal to colonize celestials bodies in space?

I think I read once that by international law, no country can colonize space. Is this true? If it is, will it apply to me as citizen of United States?

Comment: You need to be say more precisely what you mean by "colonize".

Comment: Basically establish society on another celestial body other than Earth.

Comment: Under that interpretation, establishing a society in space is completely legal, since it has nothing to do with countries of Earth.

Comment: @Nij Because of Outer Space Treaty a Sovereign nation is responsible for and required to supervise the actions of related organisations. An organisation can consist of 1 person. As a US citizen the questioner is subject to USA oversight in space.

Comment: @LOIS16192 how does the treaty apply to dual citizens?

Comment: @phoog you might pick and choose which nation will be supervising these actions, if multiple nations would agree to do so. Elon Musk is potentially a good example, holding multiple citizenships. However, it's reasonable to assume that some of them, e.g. the smaller nations, will handle the supervision and responsibility issues by a blanket policy that they disallow any operations, instead of by creating an expensive gov't agency to handle this and by assuming the financial liabilities if your launches damage something as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosmos_954 did.

Comment: Were you _so_ capable, would you ask a permission to do so? What if you don't get one? What if you fly regardless? Will they pursue you to sue you?

Comment: @phoog Multiple Sovereignty  citizenships either by choice or consequence(see note 1), typically increase your limitations. If you break the law of any of those Sovereign states anywhere, that Sovereignty can seek to arrest and after acceptable process convict, and seek to punish you. (note1 Consequence: Some states consider you are entitled to all the rights and privileges, as well as consequences  and requirements of a citizen if you pass some criteria, either time limits, ownership of property limit, there used to be weird ones like accepting the kings shilling, there may be others).

Comment: @LOIS16192 in my experience, multiple citizenships reduce limitations, since one may claim the benefits of either citizenship as one prefers.  Most criminal law is not extraterritorial.  The extraterritorial laws that do exist do not worry me.  But your comment doesn't answer my question, so I went to the [text of the treaty itself](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty_of_1967) and found that it does not in fact contain the word "citizen," so the assertion that oversight is governed by citizenship seems incorrect.

Comment: Who could stop you?

Answer (score 3):

The main treaty here is the [Outer Space Treaty](http://www.unoosa.org/oosa/en/ourwork/spacelaw/treaties/introouterspacetreaty.html) and its implementation in US law.  For your purposes, the relevant sections of the treaty are Article II:

> Outer space, including the Moon and other celestial bodies, is not subject to national appropriation by claim of sovereignty, by means of use or occupation, or by any other means.

Article VI:

> States Parties to the Treaty shall bear international responsibility for national activities in outer space, including the Moon and other celestial bodies, whether such activities are carried on by governmental agencies or by non-governmental entities...The activities of non-governmental entities in outer space, including the Moon and other celestial bodies, shall require authorization and continuing supervision by the appropriate State Party to the Treaty...

and Article VIII:

> A State Party to the Treaty on whose registry an object launched into outer space is carried shall retain jurisdiction and control over such an object, and over any personnel thereof...

Article II means that setting up your colony doesn't give you ownership over the land it sits on (and Article XII permits anyone to stop by for a visit at any time), but it doesn't outlaw setting up a permanent base.

And I hope your "all the resources" includes a small army of lawyers.  Between them, Article VI and Article VIII make the United States government responsible for anything you do in space, so there's a *lot* of paperwork involved in getting permission to do anything above the [Karman line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's entirely regulated yet.

The Article II of the [Outer Space Treaty](http://www.unoosa.org/oosa/en/ourwork/spacelaw/treaties/outerspacetreaty.html) states that *"Outer space, including the moon and other celestial bodies, is not subject to national appropriation by claim of sovereignty, by means of use or occupation, or by any other means."* And the article VII says that the only ownership that a state can have is on the artifacts used to get there or constructed there.

In theory, you can build your personal dome on Mars and live there, but you can't appropiate a single molecule, so extracting water or stone for personal use could be legally troublesome.

There is, however, the [Commercial Space Launch Competitiveness Act of 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_Space_Launch_Competitiveness_Act_of_2015) (complete text [here](https://www.congress.gov/bill/114th-congress/house-bill/2262/text)), that allows US citizens to *"engage in the commercial exploration and exploitation of 'space resources'"*. This may be a US' step toward colonization, but it obviously violates the Outer Space Treaty, and both may be overriden soon by a future act, written to suit corporative interests rather than political ones, judging by the commercial twist space exploration is taking.

Comment: Can you elaborate why "it obviously violates the Outer Space Treaty" ? As far as I see, the outer space treaty doesn't explicitly prohibit commercial exploitation of space resources, it prohibits nations from claims of sovereignty and, essentially, assigning *exclusive* rights to some space resource. In essence, USA can allow Bob to mine asteroid #1234, but (because of OST) USA isn't allowed to declare that Jacques from France can't mine asteroid #1234 because of what USA told Bob.

Comment: So, extracting water or stone for personal use is not an issue, what's legally troublesome is extracting water or stone for local resale - the other colonists can reasonably claim that the water isn't your property, you can't have *exclusive* rights to it, and you can't prevent them from using it. If you envision a local market for resources between colonies/colonists, then *that* isn't compatible with OST and lack of ownership distinctions.

Comment: @Peteris If you extract a resource from x place... are you the owner of such resource?? If not, what gives you the right to sell it?? And who gave you the authorization to mine a land that doesn't belong to you?? Under which autority, are they the owners of the land or are they claiming sovereignty over it??? Since Article VI demands that non-governmental entities require authorization and supervision by their nation, authorizing mining means appropiation by a country, which contradicts Article II.

Comment: "who gave you the authorization to mine a land that doesn't belong to you" is actually very simple - as the default legal principle is "Everything which is not forbidden is allowed", by default, you don't need authorization. You need authorization to mine land that *belongs to someone else*, and that need is caused by property rights. Absence of property rights, in general, means that you can't have *exclusive* claims, that you can't prevent others to mine "your" (i.e. not your) resource, but you certainly can mine unowned land if there aren't any other regulations explicitly prohibiting that.

Comment: "Claiming sovereignty over it" would be if you'd argue that you starting mining some place gave you some exclusivity rights for others not to mine that place, and OST prohibits that. However, you certainly can *use* a resource that's not owned by you assuming that it's also not owned by someone else, who's rights could be violated. I don't need any authorization to take water from the middle of the ocean and use it, or import it to my home. I don't own water in the middle of ocean, but neither does anyone else; and I *would* have ownership of the water that I brought home.

Comment: @Peteris Yes, but let's see if you can extract gold, uranium or any other valuable (including water which can become a very expensive fuel) and sell it without anyone bothering you. That's why you don't see swarms of people mining the Antartic.

Comment: The reason why we don't see swarms of people mining the Antarctic is because the Antarctic treaties Madrid protocol prohibits mining there. I agree on your point that likely no one in practice would be able to simply extract significant resources anywhere without others bothering them - but that wouldn't happen because of the existing treaties, but through new treaties that would be made as soon as the exploitation started to become economically relevant. However, that distinction (current regulation vs potential future regulation, de facto vs de iure) is very meaningful for LAW stackexchange.

Comment: In essence the question for this stackexchange is "Does current regulation prohibit me from doing X, and what would the *legal* consequences of X be according to *existing* law?" which is very, very different from the question of "If I'd actually do X, would other parties allow me to do it and what activities (including altering or creating law, or ignoring the law) they'll likely undertake to prevent me from doing X?" - that question is also interesting, but it's offtopic here, that can be asked on space exploration or politics stackexchange.

Comment: The 2015 law states  "It is the sense of Congress that by the enactment of this Act, the 
United States does not thereby assert sovereignty or sovereign or 
exclusive rights or jurisdiction over, or the ownership of, any 
celestial body." so no treaty violation treaty but in law there is a concept of reasonableness, so a cubic kilometer of water from the Atlantic is OK, but not from the Dead Sea. You would have need a big yard to be allowed to put a cubic Km  seawater in your home  in the USA. Space case: 1 cubic km water from Ceres or a ton from 1Km asteroid every 100 years maybe  OK,

Answer (score -3):

This is my interpretation of Space law based on conversations with people who have studied space law, law of the sea, property law, international law, and contract law in a number of countries and my own research.

The [Outer Space Treaty](http://www.unoosa.org/oosa/en/ourwork/spacelaw/treaties/outerspacetreaty.html) is the main basis, and it requires a treaty state to be responsible for the actions of any non-government or other entity.

1. The natural resources of space should benefit everyone.
2. Anything constructed belongs to the constructor.
3. The constructor is governed by the laws of their nation.
4. As a USA Citizen you are free to give up your citizenship and thus your future rights and obligations to the USA.

So assuming you offered to compensate or benefit "Everyone" fair value for what you used and some rent for the space you occupied, and you did so compliant to USA law the answer is you could go to Mars, or anywhere else extra-planetary construct what ever was necessary to function as a productive USA citizen, pay taxes and expect reasonable support from the Federal Government. Eventually a sufficiently large number of people would be able to apply for state hood.

If you choose to exercise your right to terminate your citizenship, then you need to join another sovereign treaty nation or be recognized as a sovereign nation and sign the treaty.

To pay to "Everyone" you would probably be covered if you paid some "reasonable" amount into a trust used for general benefit. 
I would suggest 10% of costs would be sufficient.

I am not a Judge (potentially able to set precedent) or even a lawyer.

I am involved in a project to simulate 1 billion plus people living in space.

Comment: I can't tell if this means "Yes you can" or "No you can't". I also don't understand how your reply related to the OST, e.g. the "need" to join another treaty signatory nation or to become a nation of your own. Where did that come from?

Comment: What if a citizen or organization from a nonsignatory nation colonizes Mars?

Comment: @phoog Anyone who wants to do it will need more than one trip and and lot of resources, including the tecnological solution to counter Mars' extremely harsh environment. There's not a chance that a "rogue colony" will be completed before the rest of Earth's nations intervene.

Comment: @LudovicoN on what basis would they intervene?  What form would the intervention take?

Comment: @phoog depending on the political context of the time there will always be a 'reason' to intervene, either by economic or military means, because... that's what we do. Nations getting in the way of other nations is, after all, what history is mainly about.

Comment: @phoog if your rocket launch crosses the airspace of any of the signatory countries without their authorization, shooting it down is a possible intervention that's clearly within their sovereign rights. If your spaceship requires any technical components or infrastructure from the signatory countries, it's reasonable that they'll prohibit their aerospace industry from supplying you anything, and prohibit their citizens from participating. There are *very* few nonsignatories. If you can launch from Namibia over the ocean, and don't need anything from the rest of the world, that'd be an option.

Comment: @phoog Good luck finding a country with space capabilities that DON'T NEED ANYTHING FROM THE REST OF THE WORLD.